Optimizing Flutter Animations for Better Performance
How can I optimize Flutter animations for smoother performance on older devices?
I'm using AnimationController and Tween for some custom animations in my Flutter app, but on older devices, the performance is lagging. Are there any best practices or optimization techniques to ensure smoother animations across different devices, especially lower-end ones
